# How to eliminate black border in maximize animation?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, firemonkey

This error/artifact occurs when any window is maximizing from normal view. 
The black area is the place on the screen where at window state = wsNormal one could see the window behind/desktop and not the form. The resizing animation makes it visible, that is the place where the form is resizing is shown to have a black color.

Is there a solution to it?

Comment: I've never noticed (or didn't understand) what you've described. Can you take a screenshot of it ?

Comment: Can't too fast. but the black thing is caught on by the eye.

Comment: Is this really a Delphi/FMX question? Isn't that animation drawn by the system?

Comment: It doesn't happen in VCL, if that's what you are interpreting.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED: LForm.WindowState := .. ` line in fmx.platform.win (XE2) and maximize the window. Is this black background what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes that's the one... I see its something all windows have in fmx :( so no resolution to this showing up? How about somehow changing it to a transparent color?

Comment: @Umair - All I know is the behavior is very same with the VCL. It is tricky to catch it: put a breakpoint on `StdWndProc` in classes with condition `(Message = WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING) and ((PWINDOWPOS(@LParam).flags and $8000) <> 0)`, maximize the window, trace in on the second hit, trace into `WM_NCCALCSIZE` that's after the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`, and you'll see the blackness in a VCL app. P.S: Include '@' before the account name when you want a commenter to be notified.